# Setting Attribute in Servlet results in null

Tags: servlets, setattribute

I try setting an attribute for a session and want to assign a String to it, that is displayed later in a jsp.
I have the following code:

The System.out results in null even thought the String was set to the error message? What am I doing wrong?

```
    error = "Something";
        session.setAttribute("error", error);
        System.out.println("This is get Attr: " +session.getAttribute(error));
```

I added the following lines of code now:

```
    RequestDispatcher disp = req.getRequestDispatcher("error.jsp");
        disp.forward(req, resp);
```

and in my jsp:

### Hello ${error}

and it is displaying ${error} instead of the value!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to access the object by key:

```
System.out.println("This is get Attr: " +session.getAttribute("error"));
```

In your example, you are using the value (i.e.the object reference *error*)

Comment: Thanks EJK! With the JSP, however, it still doesnt work. Any idea why?

Comment: Ah, I see you have updated your post with the JSP code...  The syntax you use is JSTL Expression Language (EL).  That will work if your page is properly configured to evaluate EL.  I think that can be turned on by adding a page directive.  Give me a minute to look that up...

Comment: And here is the directive to add to the top of your JSP:  <%@ page isELIgnored="false" %>

Comment: I did the same error page in another application, and did not need the directive there, any idea why?!

Comment: @Mysia - from what I have read, EL is supposed to be enabled by default, but some servlet containers default to disabled.